# Does QGIS read NAS data?

Tags: qgis

I wonder if it is possible to load German NAS-Data into QGIS or to convert them to Shapefiles. I'm using QGIS 1.8 on Ubuntu 12.04.

NAS is the new Geodata-format, based on ALKIS-Data:
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normbasierte_Austauschschnittstelle

I installed the current Master on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine today and typed "ogr2org --formats" but NAS didn't appear on the list.

If I check my ogr-version it says 1.7.3 - as I understood NAS is supported from 1.8.0 onwards.

Did you do anything special to install that version?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could explain, what NAS stands for in your use case:  http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAS

Comment: Could you try running "ogr2ogr --formats" (without the quotes)? Here, in Ubuntu 12.04 QGIS Master, NAS appears in the list as a supported format. N.

Comment: yes it does http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_nas.html

Comment: No, I didn't do anything special. But I'm in Ubuntu and perhaps you're in Windows? For some reason the development versions of QGIS appear to come with older versions of GDAL/OGR than the current stable versions of QGIS. In Ubuntu my version of Master came with GDAL/OGR 1.8.

Comment: Nope, standalone Qgis 1.8.0 on Windows 7 running here with GDAL 1.9.1, and NAS included. BTW, the format list is NOT alphabetical. Anyway, the asker is on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: As far as I know, there is an [ALKIS plugin for QGIS](http://www.norbit.de/75/)